# Update child component in React with data from other child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am pretty new to React and am trying to solve something right now but somehow can't get my head around the rendering process of React.
I have three components: 1 parent component, 2 child components.

Parent component is called "GaStructuresApp".
Child 1 component is called "DropdownTreeSelect".
Child 2 component is called "Keywords".

GaStructuresApp receives data from an external system via an useEffect() hook and sets the received data via useState on the "DropdownTreeSelect" component.
I can now navigate via the structure in that child component and select different values (via checkbox). Every value in that checkbox has child-elements. These child-elements however should appear next to the "DropdownTreeSelect" component in an own div.
For this, I have the "Keywords" component which receives the child-elements of the selected item via props. Thus, I am also setting the value via a useEffect() for that component.
This works fine as well. However, now the "DropdownTreeSelect" component is collapsed again and nothing is checked. This is probably due to the fact that everything got re-rendered again.
I do not want the "DropdownTreeSelect" to re-render when I click the checkbox. I only want the "Keywords" component to re-render, since that component received the new props.

Here is some code (obfuscated to the important points):

"GaStructuresApp":

```
export default function GaStructuresApp() {

    const [keywordsAll, setKeywords] = useState([]);

...

    function onChange(currentNode, selectedNodes) {

        keywordsAll.splice(0, keywordsAll.length);
        setKeywords([...keywordsAll]);


        selectedNodes.forEach(node => {
            if (node.checked === true) {
                if (node.kids.length > 0) {
                    getChildrenValues(node);
                }
                else {
                    node.keywords?.forEach(keyword => {
                        keywordsAll.push(keyword);

                        setKeywords([...keywordsAll]);
                    })
                }
            }
        })

        buildPaths(selectedNodes);
    }

...

return(<> <div className={"dropdown"}><DropdownTreeSelect data={data} onChange={onChange} showDropdown={"always"}/> </div> <Keywords keywords={keywordsAll}/> </>)
```

"Keywords":

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Keywords ({keywords}) {

    return (
        <div className={"keywordsBox"}>
            <ul>
                {keywords.map((keyword) => (
                    <li id={keyword.id}>
                        {keyword.value}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>


    );
}
```